# Detecting size of a dynamic DIV container of a 3rd party website

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, web, size

I am trying to come up with a Javascript code to get the size of a dynamic `div` container which is displayed to another user containing the data of a 3rd party website.

I have a `div` container which parses a link of a 3rd party website and that 3rd party website displays the content depending on the visitor (dynamic content) 
and size also gets changed every now and then. I will be adding that `div` container code to my website.

If someone visits my webpage he / she would see that dynamic content in that `div` container having some height and width .

I was thinking if it would be possible to know what the size of the `div` container is, so that it is visible to the visitor using JavaScript code or something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, due to the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you cannot access any elements on a 3rd party website.